# Get the product category terms from cart items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, taxonomy-terms

I only get the product category on some producs, on some I don't

```
function savings_33_55_cart() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) { 
        for ($i=0; $i < $cart_item['quantity'] ; $i++) {   
            $productId = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

            echo "PROD ID: " . $productId . "<br>";

            $terms = get_the_terms( $productId, 'product_cat' );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $product_cat = $term->name;
                echo "PRODUCT CATEGORY: " . $product_cat . "<br>"; 
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'savings_33_55_cart' );
```

I expect to get a product category on every product, but I only get the product category on some products

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec! I just changed the line $productId = $cart_item['data']->get_id(); to $productId = $cart_item['product_id']; and now it works

Comment: can you also mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Don't ask questions which include the word "Solved". If you have a solution, accept an answer.

Comment: opensource-developer and Quentin, Thanks for your comments. I'm new here, I have accepted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `$product_cat` variable is not defined.

**To get a product category on cart items**, you need to get the parent variable product ID for product variations as they don't handle custom taxonomies as product categories or product tags.

> **To get the correct product ID for any custom taxonomy terms on cart items always use**:
>
> ```
> $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
> ```
>
> Instead of:
>
> ```
> $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
> ```

Now if you need to get the product category **term names**, instead of using `get_the_terms()` function, you can use `wp_get_post_terms()` and `implode()` functions like:

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', ['fields' => 'names'] );

// Displaying term names in a coma separated string
if( count( $term_names ) > 0 )
    echo __("Product categories") . ": " . implode( ", ", $term_names ) . '<br>':

// OR displaying term names as a vertical list
if( count( $term_names ) > 0 )
    echo __("Product categories") . ": " . implode( "<br>", $term_names ) . '<br>';
```

So in a cart items foreach loop:

```
// Loop through cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $quantity     = $cart_item['quantity']; 
    $product_id   = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];

    echo __("PRODUCT ID: ") . $product_id . "<br>";

    $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'names') );

    if ( count($term_names) > 0 ) {
        echo __("PRODUCT CATEGORY: ") . implode("<br>", $term_names) . "<br>";
    }
}
```